# Characterization of the space of integrable functions stable under multiplication

Tags: measure-theory

Let $Ω = (Ω,Σ_Ω,μ)$ be a measure space and let $L(Ω)$ be the space of integrable functions on $Ω$.

For $f ∈ L(Ω)$, set $L_f(Ω) = \{φ ∈ L(Ω);~f·φ ∈ L(Ω)\}$.

Has the space of all integrable functions stable under multiplication by integrable functions
$$\bigcap_{f ∈ L(Ω)} L_f(Ω)$$
a nice characterization when $Ω$ is an Euclidean space $ℝ^n$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure, say in terms of continuity? Are there characterizations for more general $Ω$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, this intersection is $L^\infty(\Omega)$, the set of bounded measurable functions.

It is clear that $L^\infty(\Omega)\subset L_f(\Omega)$ for any $f\in L(\Omega)$.
The other direction is trickier.
Let us denote the intersection by $I$.
If $f\in I$, then $f\in L_f(\Omega)$ and so $f^2\in L(\Omega)$.
But $f\in I\subset L_{f^2}(\Omega)$, so $f^3\in L(\Omega)$.
Carrying on like this, we have that $f^k\in L(\Omega)$ (or $f\in L^k(\Omega)$) for any $k\in\mathbb N$.
This implies that $f\in\bigcap_{p\in\mathbb N} L^p(\Omega)=L^\infty(\Omega)$.

Even if $\Omega$ has infinite measure, the argument above shows that $L(\Omega)\cap L^\infty(\Omega)\subset I\subset\bigcap_{p\in\mathbb N} L^p(\Omega)$.